# How to use ck_list in a struct?

Tags: c, struct

I'm using the library http://concurrencykit.org/, more specifically I'm using `CK_LIST` a multi-reader single-writer linked list. There's no examples or documentation I can find online other than the unit and regression test that come with concurrencyKit, but I figured out how to use `CK_LIST` on it's own, which can be seen below.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ck_queue.h>

struct list_node
{
    void *data;

    CK_LIST_ENTRY(list_node) list_entry;

};

static CK_LIST_HEAD(list, list_node) list = CK_LIST_HEAD_INITIALIZER(list);

int main(void)
{
    struct list_node *node, *node2;

    CK_LIST_INIT(&list);

    node = malloc(sizeof(struct list_node));
    if(node == NULL)
    {
        perror("malloc");
        return -1;
    }

    int rtrn = asprintf((char **)&node->data, "test");
    if(rtrn < 0)
    {
        perror("asprintf");
        free(node);
        return -1;
    }

    CK_LIST_INSERT_HEAD(&list, node, list_entry);

    CK_LIST_FOREACH(node2, &list, list_entry)
    {
        printf("out: %s\n", node2->data);
    }

    free(node->data);
    free(node);
    
    return 0;
}
```

However I want to use `CK_LIST` inside of a struct so that I can mmap it as shared memory and use the list across multiple processes. But when I try to use `CK_LIST` inside a struct I get compiler errors.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ck_queue.h>

struct shared_data
{
    CK_LIST_HEAD(list, list_node) list;
};

struct list_node
{
    void *data;

    CK_LIST_ENTRY(list_node) list_entry;

};

int main(void)
{
    struct list_node *node, *node2;
    struct shared_data *data;

    node = malloc(sizeof(struct list_node));
    if(node == NULL)
    {
        perror("malloc");
        return -1;
    }

    data->list = CK_LIST_HEAD_INITIALIZER(data->list);

    CK_LIST_INIT(&data->list);

    int rtrn = asprintf((char **)&node->data, "test");
    if(rtrn < 0)
    {
        perror("asprintf");
        free(node);
        return -1;
    }

    CK_LIST_INSERT_HEAD(&data->list, node, list_entry);

    CK_LIST_FOREACH(node2, &data->list, list_entry)
    {
        printf("out: %s\n", node2->data);
    }

    free(node->data);
    free(node);
    
    return 0;
}
```

So how do you use `CK_LIST` inside a struct?

## Edit

Here is the compiler output.

```
ck_list_test.c:32:18: error: expected expression
    data->list = CK_LIST_HEAD_INITIALIZER(data->list);
                 ^
/usr/local/include/ck_queue.h:339:2: note: expanded from macro 'CK_LIST_HEAD_INITIALIZER'
        { NULL }
        ^
1 error generated.
```

Comment: What compiler errors do you get? What is the post-preprocessing output of `CK_LIST_ENTRY(list_node)` inside the `struct`?

Comment: I added the compiler output and the post-processed output was `struct list { struct list_node *lh_first; } list;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe I found the answer, just initialize a struct with `CK_LIST_HEAD_INITIALIZER()` and then take a pointer to it, like so.

```
struct shared_data mapping = { .list = CK_LIST_HEAD_INITIALIZER(mapping->list) };
struct shared_data *map = &mapping;
```